# Reference for proof matrix analysis

Tags: matrices

I am looking for a quick reference (or if anyone could directly provide) for the proof of the following theorem from Horn's and Johsnon Matrix Analysis.

A series $\sum a_k A^k$ converges if there $\exists$ a norm $\|\mathbf{.}\|$ such that $\sum |a_k| \|A\|^k$ is convergent (or have bounded partial sums).

$\|\mathbf{.}\|$ is a matrix norm and verifies submultiplicativity.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define convergence if not by norms?

Comment: Is asking about the "absolute convergence" (quotes because I don't know if the name is standard).

Comment: I mean convergence of the actual matrices, of the Neumann-series-like. Isnt such thing possible?

Comment: Yes, $a^k$. Its correct now. This is somewhat unknown territory for me, so references would be of great help aswell!

Comment: Yes, I write $\|\mathbf{.}\|$ to mean a matrix norm.

Comment: What do you mean by a matrix norm?

Comment: It verifies the usual norm properties aswell as submultiplicativity.

Comment: Submultiplicativity is the key here, you might want to emphasize that in the question. (For example, with the norm $\|A\|_* = {1 \over 4}\|A\|_2$, then for $A=2I, a =1$ the right hand side above is satisfied, but clearly the left hand side is infinite.)

Comment: Alright, thanks. Edited the post.

Comment: I suppose that $a^k$ is actually $a_k$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my memory serves me, you can prove that the partial sums are a Cauchy sequence via the triangle inequality and the property $||AB||\le||A||\ ||B||$.

EDIT: Let be $m>n$:
$$
||\sum_{k=0}^m a_k A^k-\sum_{k=0}^n a_k A^k||=
||\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k A^k||\le
\sum_{k=n+1}^m |a_k|\,||A^k||\le
\sum_{k=n+1}^m |a_k|\,||A||^k.
$$